# ничего не выводится на страницу со всеми продуктами в Django

Tags: django

Есть модель с тремя классами категория-подкатегория-продукты

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Название категории', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='Изображение')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_category


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='категория', related_name='sub')
    name_subcategory = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Название подкатегории', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='Изображение')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_subcategory


class Product(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='категория',related_name='prod')
    name_product = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Название товара', max_length = 100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/", verbose_name='Изображение')
    price = models.IntegerField('цена')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_product
```

мой views.py

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    """список категорий"""
    model = Category


class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    """Полное описание фильма"""
    model = Category
    

class SubcategoryDetailView(ListView):
    """список продуктов"""
    model = Subcategory
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.CategoryView.as_view()),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'), 
    path('<slug:slug>/<slug:slug_sub>/', views.SubcategoryView.as_view(), name='subcategory_list'),
]
```

шаблон страницы с которой перехожу на страницу со всеми продуктами(category_detail.html)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} 
<h2>{{ category.name_category }}</h2>
   {% for sub in category.sub.all %}
      <a href="{% url 'subcategory_list' slug=category.slug slug_sub=sub.slug %}"> {{sub.name_subcategory}}</a>
      <img src="{{sub.image.url}}" width="100px" height="100px">
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

шаблон страницы(subcategory_list.html) со всеми продуктами(тут я не написал вывод продуктов т.к. не передается даже и название подкатегории)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} 
    {{sub.name_subcategory}}
{% endblock %}
```

никак не могу понять почему на последнюю страницу ничего не выводит. Возможно проблема в классах во views т.к. раньше пробовал писать только через функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

смотри как получается:
у тебя `SubcategoryDetailView` должен быть наследником `DetailView`, ты ведь получаешь подробную информацию о конкретном объекте `SubCategory`, либо делай его ListView для модели `Product`.
Если поменять на DetailView, то нужно еще указать, что информация о подкатегории будет брать по не по параметру `slug` а `slug_sub`(slug - относится к категории).
Так же, ты обращаешься в шаблоне к объекту как `sub`, то нужно указать это во вью

```
class SubcategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    """список продуктов"""
    model = Subcategory
    slug_url_kwarg = "slug_sub"
    context_object_name = 'sub'
```

и не забудь переименовать html файл с `subcategory_list.html` в `subcategory_detail.html`

Comment: Что так сложно с классами..писал раньше только функциями , так вроде все более компактно написано, но не очень понятно. Есть вообще какая-нибудь принципиальная разница как писать функции или классы?

Comment: на самом деле не сложно, просто нужно привыкнуть. С классами код, на мой взгляд, компактней и легче читается. А так как и везде в программировании любую задачу можно решить несколькими способами и каждый сам решает, какой из способов ему предпочтительней